How to assign a Named Key Range in Excel VBA
I am new to Excel VBA. I want to sort an column in a Table using VBA code. My Table name will be dynamic. So a string is created.
Sub Macro3()
'
' Macro3 Macro
'

'
    Dim TN As String
    
    
    Range("A11").Select
    TN = ActiveCell.ListObject.Name
        
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Base Unit").ListObjects(TN).Sort.SortFields _
        .Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Base Unit").ListObjects(TN).Sort.SortFields _
        .Add2 Key:=Range("Base_Unit[[#All],[Cabinet Number]]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Base Unit").ListObjects(TN).Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub

I want to give a string to .Add2 Key Range
.Add2 Key:=Range("Base_Unit[[#All],[Cabinet Number]]"),.
Is it possible?
I tried to give a name to the Key Range butut an error occured.

error Occurs isn't really helpful. What was the complete, exact error message you got?

Sort Excel Table

Use (object) variables for the table (ListObject) and the sort column range.

Simple
Sub SortTable()

    Dim lo As ListObject:
    Set lo = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Base Unit").Range("A11").ListObject
    
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = lo.ListColumns("Cabinet Number").Range
    
    With lo.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=crg, _
            SortOn:= xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub

Educational
Sub SortTableStepByStep()

    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Base Unit"
    Const TABLE_CELL_ADDRESS As String = "A11"
    Const COLUMN_HEADER As String = "Cabinet Number"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    Dim locell As Range: Set locell = ws.Range(TABLE_CELL_ADDRESS)
    Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = locell.ListObject
    Dim lc As ListColumn: Set lc = lo.ListColumns(COLUMN_HEADER)
    Dim crg As Range: Set crg = lc.Range
    
    With lo.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=crg, _
            SortOn:= xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    
End Sub

No Variable (Not recommended)
Sub SortTableNoVariable()
    ' In this case, the parent (object) of the 'Sort' object
    ' is the table i.e. a 'ListObject' object.
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Base Unit").Range("A11").ListObject.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Parent.ListColumns("Cabinet Number").Range, _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

Sub SortTableConcat()
    ' In this case, the parent (object) of the 'Sort' object
    ' is the table i.e. a 'ListObject' object.
    ' The parent (object) of the 'ListObject' object
    ' is always the worksheet i.e. a 'Worksheet' object.
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Base Unit").Range("A11").ListObject.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add2 Key:=.Parent.Parent _
            .Range(.Parent.Name & "[[#All],[Cabinet Number]]"), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub

